# Writing macros on file defined at compilation time

Tags: macros, expl3

This is a follow-up to this [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47519/stripping-a-pair-of-double-quote-characters-surrounding-a-word-and-define-it-as). I have a LaTeX3 code that reads a file formatted as follows:

```
 <numberA> "<nameA>"
 <numberB> "<nameB>"
 <numberC> "<nameC>"
 ...
```

and defines `\nameA` as `numberA`, `\nameB` as `numberB`, etc. Here is the code:

```
 \documentclass{article}

 \begin{filecontents*}{myinput.txt}
    0.45 "wingTaperRatio"
    12.0 "wingSpanMT"
    10.2 "wingAreaMTSquared"
 \end{filecontents*}

 \usepackage{xparse}
 \ExplSyntaxOn
 \ior_new:N \l_ago_read_s

 \iow_new:N \l_ago_write_s % I want to write on file as well

 \tl_new:N \l_ago_read_tl
 \NewDocumentCommand{\parseInput}{ m }
   {
    \ior_open:Nn \l_ago_read_s { #1 }

    \iow_open:Nn \l_ago_write_s { mydefs.tex } % write this file!

    \group_begin: \tex_endlinechar:D \c_minus_one
    \bool_until_do:nn { \ior_if_eof_p:N \l_ago_read_s }
      {
       \ior_to:NN \l_ago_read_s \l_ago_read_tl
       \tl_if_empty:NF \l_ago_read_tl
       { \exp_after:wN \ago_process_line:w \l_ago_read_tl \q_stop }

       % \iow_now:Nx \l_ago_write_s  ???

      }
    \group_end:
    \ior_close:N \l_ago_read_s
    \iow_close:N \l_ago_write_s
   }

 \cs_new:Npn \ago_process_line:w #1 ~ " #2 " \q_stop
   {
    \cs_gset:cpn { #2 } { #1 }
   }

 \ExplSyntaxOff

 \begin{document}

 \parseInput{myinput.txt}

 \wingTaperRatio, \wingSpanMT, \wingAreaMTSquared.

 \end{document}
```

The question is: How the above code has to be modified in order to have all the definitions in `mydefs.tex` as follow?

```
 \def\wingTaperRatio{0.45}
 \def\wingSpanMT{12.0}
 \def\wingAreaMTSquared{10.2}
```

Comment: I don't really understand. Do you want a `mydefs.tex` file to be generated from your input data?

Comment: @Daniel Yep, the goal is taking those macro names contained in `myinput.txt` and get the file `mydefs.tex` with macros defined in TeX.

Comment: Any educational reason to do it with TeX? Otherwise I would recommend an `sed`, `awk` or `perl` one-liner.

Comment: @Daniel The file `mydefs.tex` with with macro definitions is meant to be reused by a larger project. The above code can serve to prepare recapitulatory tables of data produced in a given folder. See http://www.guitex.org/home/images/meeting2012/slides/presentazione_demarco_guitmeeting_2012.pdf

Comment: Sure. The same would hold for a `sed` script. It just seems a bit strange to use TeX for a simple text file subtitutions, but of course, you can do it :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change the definition of `\ago_process_line:w` to

```
\cs_new:Npn \ago_process_line:w #1 ~ " #2 " \q_stop
 {
  \cs_gset:cpn { #2 } { #1 }
  \iow_now:Nx \l_ago_write_s { \def \exp_not:c { #2 } \exp_not:n { { #1 } } }
 }
```

With `\exp_not:c` the control sequence name is formed and written unexpanded. (Thanks to Joseph Wright for the improvement.)

Here's the contents of `mydefs.tex` that I get:

```
\def \wingTaperRatio {0.45}
\def \wingSpanMT {12.0}
\def \wingAreaMTSquared {10.2}
```

Comment: You want `\exp_not:c` rather than using `\cs:w` ... `\cs_end:` here.

Comment: @JosephWright As usual, too many functions. :)